# Can we access two URL's for single Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular world. I need to create application having two base URL. I am having distributed DB which is horizontally fragmented according to institutewise.

Scenario is that,

1. In one functionality, Admin or any other user can logged in and navigate to the application menu and proceed the further application.
2. In another functionality, only admin is allowed to access this login page , it will navigate to manage institute page. and further will work with manage institute page only.

So how I can achieve this two functionality in one application with two separate logins? Or I need to create two separate applications for two functionality?

Comment: Actually it deals with RBAC ie Role base Access control, create a Role as user and admin, map the appropriate URL they are accessed to navigate in your router use Guards to check for the Roles

Comment: How to map URL for particular User in angular 2? Can you please elaborate how this could happen?

Comment: still you have doubts ?.

Comment: Thank you. I got solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do not want to create 2 applications to solve this problem. Just create user accounts, where some users are Admins and others are not.

Then in Angular you use route guards to protect the functionality/pages/routes that you only want Admin users to see. Other users will not have access to 'Admin' routes.

You can read all about that [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) and [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html).

For example, you can declare routes with a guard like this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '/admin', 
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

You can see that the route `/admin` has a guard, which will check if the user is of type admin and return true/false. If false, the user cannot visit that route and so the AdminComponent will not be rendered.

The `/profile` route does not have a guard, so all users can visit their profile route/page.

Comment: But what about security? Can it will not be get hacked by persons easily?

Comment: Your users should be logging in with a username and password, which is stored in your database and authenticated via your API. Then after they login your API should issue a JSON WebToken. Please read the links I provided and also this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: Thank-you so much for your valuable time and information.